# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () + .ttf file on wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

I have a custom font uploaded to the WordPress site. It does not seem to be working on few of the web pages. I was able to identify that the font(source link)for the font on the pages are different. But, i'm not sure how to locate and modify the sources CSS for the website. I'm fairly new to wordpress and this is a Website implemented by a third party.

It would be helpful to know the location on the WordPress where the source can be modified.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (): CustomFont.ttf
```

Comment: How do you load the font, in CSS? Because it is strange that it loads in just in some pages

Comment: The custom font link was incorrect on that specific page. Plus, it uses a different template. So, I have to figure out the link for this page's template and change the Font link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with:

1. Open your website /wp-content/themes/**theme_name** folder in a  good editor like Visual Studio Code, sublime, Notepad++, etc.
2. Search for the font file name **CustomFont.ttf** in all files.

That should point you to where it is located.

Comment: Found it. Thanks for that.